# typescript-angular unknown provider issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, typescript1.5

Facing this issue while injecting StateService in Controller

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: StateServiceProvider <-
>   StateService

```
//Service
module ba.entry {
  export class StateService{
        constructor () {}
  }

  angular
      .module('ba.entry')
      .service('ba.entry.StateService', StateService);
}


// Controller
module ba.entry {

    export class StateController {

        static $inject = ['$scope', 'ba.entry.StateService'];

        constructor (public $scope: Scope, stateService) {}
    }

    angular
        .module('ba.entry')
        .controller('ba.entry.StateController', StateController);

}
```

// App Configuration

```
module ba {

    'use strict';
        angular.module('ba.entry', []);

        angular
            .module('betting-assistance', [
                'ui.router',
                'AutoCompleteApp'
            ]);
}
```

Comment: What module are you referencing in `ng-app`, `ba.entry` or `betting-assistance`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module

> ba.entry

was not loaded as dependency

> betting-assistance

```
module ba {

    'use strict';
        angular.module('ba.entry', []);

        angular
            .module('betting-assistance', [
                'ui.router',
                'ba.entry',
                'AutoCompleteApp'
            ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your service like this:

```
.service('ba.entry.StateService', StateService);
```

and your $inject statement is defined like this

```
static $inject = ['$scope', 'StateService'];
```

The issue is that $inject takes the string that is being used when it is registered into the angular module, so change your inject statement to be...

```
static $inject = ['$scope', 'ba.entry.StateService'];
```

The other issue I see is that you're trying to inject a service as a module...

```
angular.module('ba.entry', ['ba.entry.StateService']);
```

should be:

```
angular.module('ba.entry', []);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.Yeah, I had tried this too its giving the same error.